# Cadence cluster not coming up on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, cadence-workflow

I am trying get cadence running on a kubernetes cluster.
However, I noticed there's a bug in the Cadence server initialization which prevents Cassandra scripts from running to properly initialize schema. https://github.com/uber/cadence/issues/1713
So I thought I would do this step manually. 
I performed the following steps -

- kompose convert on the docker compose from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uber/cadence/master/docker/docker-compose.yml
- kubectl apply -f cassandra-deployment.yaml
- Run the container locally copy the cadence-cassandra-tool(usr/local/bin/cadence-cassandra-tool) and
  cassandra(/etc/cadence/schema/cassandra) folder  from local container
  to local directory
- Copy these two files to cassandra pods
- login into the cassandra pod
- Run the following command on the container

```
/cadence-cassandra-tool --ep 127.0.0.1 -k cadence setup-schema -v 0.0
/cadence-cassandra-tool --ep 127.0.0.1 -k cadence update-schema -d /cassandra/cadence/versioned
/cadence-cassandra-tool --ep 127.0.0.1 create -k cadence_visibility --rf 1
/cadence-cassandra-tool --ep 127.0.0.1 -k cadence_visibility setup-schema -v 0.0
/cadence-cassandra-tool --ep 127.0.0.1 -k cadence_visibility update-schema -d /cassandra/visibility/versioned
exit
```

At this point I checked `describe keyspaces;` via. cqlsh and I don't see these keyspaces created in cassandra!

- Run cassandra service, stastd, cadence-service, cadence-web and expose it to cluster.
  What i noticed is that cadence service is up and I can get on the UI. We have exposed the cadence-service and cadence-web using Load balancer so I can reach the IP from my local.

What I noticed is the cadence-service pod is not running. I get the following error -

```
cassandra started
2019/11/19 23:39:30 Loading config; env=docker,zone=,configDir=/etc/cadence/config
2019/11/19 23:39:30 Loading configFiles=[/etc/cadence/config/docker.yaml]
2019/11/19 23:39:30 error: failed to connect to 10.196.243.88:9042 due to error: Keyspace 'cadence' does not exist
2019/11/19 23:39:30 error: failed to connect to 10.196.13.25:9042 due to error: Keyspace 'cadence' does not exist
2019/11/19 23:39:30 error: failed to connect to 10.196.243.88:9042 due to error: Keyspace 'cadence' does not exist
2019/11/19 23:39:30 Incompatible versionsunable to create CQL Client: no connections were made when creating the session
```

Any pointers on how to get it up? 
Thanks.

Comment: Please take a look at this [helm repo](https://hub.helm.sh/charts/banzaicloud-stable/cadence)

Comment: @Hanx thanks, is this a practice that everyone uses helm to deploy cadence on kubernates? I am quite new to this so looking for suggestions.

Comment: I have no experience with cadence but you are trying "kubernetise" this deployment -  so in this case if there exists stable ready helm chart it will be easier.

Comment: I see.. I will give this a try. Appreciate your inputs!

Answer (score 0):

There is a helm repo https://hub.helm.sh/charts/banzaicloud-stable/cadence which helped solved this issue.